# Cannot plot simple matplotlib plot due to module not found

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm just trying to do this simple plot but the following error is occurring.

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I have tried updating `matplotlib` and tried to `pip install kiwisolver` but still this error is coming:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MY STUFF\softwares\New folder\First.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "D:\MY STUFF\softwares\New folder\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "D:\MY STUFF\softwares\New folder\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 194, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "D:\MY STUFF\softwares\New folder\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kiwisolver'
```

Comment: Could you install kiwisolver successfully?

Comment: Yes , i successfully installed it

Comment: Is there any issue of python environments? Can you import kiwisolver on the same terminal?

Comment: No , it giving error on the same terminal

Comment: Try installing both packages in same environment. And cross check on terminal before running any script.

Comment: But this error did not used to come before like in python 3.7 but it is coming after i updated to python 3.8

Comment: Looking at kiwisolver PyPi page, it looks like working with Python 3.7 would be better. 3.8 is new, so might cause issues.